# Not able to get the values using Gson

Tags: java, json, list, gson

I have List Object.that list i am passing to Gson.

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String toJson = gson.toJson(userDetailFeedNotifierVoList);
        System.out.println("Gson Object : " + toJson);
```

Here I am getting in console :

```
[
{
    "title": "Suman Mudiraj assigned you a to-do item named test todo in the Launch GALAXY activity.",
    "time": "2014-10-08T10:51:07.095Z",
    "url": "https://greenhouse.lotus.com/activities/service/html/mainpage#activitypage,0c7b1fb5-a87f-4112-9b7f-67ed6bd0233f,entry=634e9535-ba17-40da-a242-bd9caff6f17d",
    "schedullarTime": 0
},
{
    "title": "Suman Mudiraj assigned you a to-do item named test todo in the Launch GALAXY activity.",
    "time": "2014-10-08T10:51:07.095Z",
    "url": "https://greenhouse.lotus.com/activities/service/html/mainpage#activitypage,0c7b1fb5-a87f-4112-9b7f-67ed6bd0233f,entry=634e9535-ba17-40da-a242-bd9caff6f17d",
    "schedullarTime": 0
}
```

]

Here i want to get title and url.Can you Please suggest me?

Comment: You can either mark the field as transient or use the @Expose annotation if you want to exclude them from the serialization process.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need specific fields, you can use `@Expose` [see gson docs](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Gson-s-Expose) on these fields:

```
class UserDetailFeedNotifierVo
{
   @Expose
   String title;

   @Expose
   String url;

   //not exposed
   String time;
}
```

To use it:

```
Gson gson = GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
String toJson = gson.toJson(userDetailFeedNotifierVoList);
System.out.println("Gson Object : " + toJson);
```

Comment: This Userdetails is he bean class or what?here i have to write Annotation or what/

Comment: @mdrazi Well what's the datatype of `userDetailFeedNotifierVoList`?

Comment: List<userDetailFeedNotifierVoList>

Comment: @mdrazi So `UserDetail` is equivalent to your `userDetailFeedNotifierVoList` class.

Comment: i have Mention...  List<UserDetailFeedNotifierVo> userDetailFeedNotifierVoList = null;   @ZouZou

Comment: UserDetailFeedNotifierVo is bean class,where i have declare title and url,etc...  @ZouZou

Comment: @mdrazi Yes, so what's the problem? This answer already gives you the solution.

Comment: Yeah @ZouZou i have added Annotation in My PoJO Class.and what u wrote previously i have added all into my code but i am unable to get title and URl

Comment: @mdrazi Then you did something wrong because this answer should work.

Comment: I have in that bean                                             @Expose
private String title;

Comment: Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();               here i wrote like this.....@ZouZou

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `transient` modifier to members in class that you don't want to be serialized.

```
  // will be serialized
  private String propertyOne;

  // will not be serialized
  private transient String propertyTwo;
```